# Physical mouse click vs simulated button click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, click

Hello Stackoverflow!

I am experimenting with getting a chrome extensions cript to click a page button to trigger an AJAX request, however it would seem that physically clicking said button is not the same as using the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[10].click();
```

the results of the getElements line is this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue ...">
```

Using document.forms sort of works, but unfortunately reloads the page, which is not what happens when the Ajaxrequest is fired by the click event.

```
document.forms[1].submit();
```

Calling the form returns the following:

```
<form
action="/battle.php" method="post" name="2913" id="2913" onsubmit="get('/battle.php', '', this);
disableSubmitButton(this);
return false;">…</form>
```

Doesn't seem obvious to a beginner programmer like me, why using the .click(); in F12 console (chrome) would be any different from the physical click. Also i have verified (sorf of) that the button on the screen is in fact the one i'm calling with the getElementsByTagName('input').

Answer (score 0):

The page reloads because the type of the button is "submit". You could attach an event handler to the "click" button that can submit the form without reloading the page. Your code will look something like this:

Using JQuery:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // stops default submit
   $('#2913').submit(); // or the ID of your form
});
```

And your HTML will be :

```
<input type="button" value="Continue ..." id="submitButton">
```